# Question on differentiation/finding the derivative of an equation (in calculus)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The equation of a parabola is given as $y= 3x^2 - 12x$

- Find $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$

$$\begin{align}y=& 3x^2 - 12x\\
  =&3(2x) - ???\end{align}$$

What do you do with the $12x$?
I know this seems extremely comical seeing as how easy it must be for you mathematical geniuses but... I'm still new to calculus and I really need help.

Comment: No need to shout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done it right for the first term $3x^2$ using the power rule and getting $3(2x)=6x$

For the second term, $-12x$, you have an easier way to get it .

Note that $ y=-12x$ is a the equation of a straight line and since derivatives are nothing but slopes  we will get $y'= -12$ out of $y=-12x$

Of course you may use the power rule again considering that the power of $x$ in $-12x$ is $1$ and as the result we will have $ -12x^0 = -12$

Comment: Great help sir. Thanks very much

Comment: @D.Nikao  Thanks for your attention and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Given $k$ is a constant, derivative of $kx^n$ is given by,

$$\frac{d(kx^n)}{dx}=k(nx^{n-1})$$

Can you use the same rule to find derivative of $12x$?

Comment: So its..just 12?

Comment: @D.Nikao yes. The constant $12$.

Comment: @D.Nikao Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You were solving it correctly. Recall the following property.

$$\frac{d}{dx} f(x)\pm g(x) = \frac{d}{dx} f(x)\pm\frac{d}{dx} g(x)$$

You can find the derivative of each individual term and add/subtract them to get the derivative of the given function.

$$\frac{d}{dx} 3x^2-12x = \frac{d}{dx} 3x^2-\frac{d}{dx} 12x$$

Now use the Power Rule for both individual parts.

$$\frac{d}{dx} ax^n = anx^{n-1} \implies \frac{d}{dx}3x^2 = 6x$$

$$\implies \frac{d}{dx} 12x = 12$$

Now, subtract.

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 6x-12$$

Comment: Thanks soo much man i actually get it now.

Comment: Could you just give me a similar question so that i could test it out again.. please

Comment: Well, there really isn’t much to test here. You deduct one from the exponent, and move the exponent in front of the term as a coefficient. For instance, $\frac{d}{dx} 5x^3 = 5(3)x^{3-1} = 15x^2$. If your function is in the form $f(x)\pm g(x)$, you can break it down into two parts and solve them individually, followed by adding/subtracting them, as mentioned before.